# append after detach doesn't work in jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanna detach some nodes and after a while append them to the same parent node. I tried to use this source code below. It’s doesn’t work. But when I remove the detach method its work find.

Form (it’s doesn’t work):

```
$("#left_select").detach();
$("#left_select").append("&lt;div>test&lt;/div>");
```

To (it’s what I am talking about, but I wanna remove some nodes):

```
$("#left_select").append("&lt;div>test&lt;/div>");
```

Would detach method remove parent node? Or I got something miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you detach an element, it does not exists in the dom any more so any query selector that you use in the document context will not be able to find the element. That is why your code is not working(when you use `$("#left_select")` after detach the `#left_select` is not found in the document).

So the solution is to have a variable reference to the detached element, and use the variable in the following code to refer the detached element

```
var $form = $("#left_select").detach();
$form.append("&lt;div>test&lt;/div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. So I needa create another parent node to make sure it's connecting with dom.